# Using JavaScript to change background-image in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, background-image

I am very new to JavaScript. Following line works for FF and Chrome, but not for IE 11:

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header").item(0);       
header.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/banner1.png'), url('./images/banner2.png')";
```

Any idea why not?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/5Q5H8/

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change your logic to target the body element rather than the header element.

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);       
header.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/banner1.png'), url('./images/banner2.png')";
```

**P.S.**  You may want to change the name of the variable you create to something other than header, but I'll leave that up to you.

Hope this helps!